# How to retrieve taxonomy term name in url instead of id in a drupal view?

Tags: php, drupal, taxonomy, drupal-10, listview-filter

I'm currently working on Drupal 10 and utilizing Views with filter criteria. However, when I apply filters to my view, it shows the ID of the taxonomy term instead of its name. How can I ensure that it displays the name of the term instead of the ID? Essentially, I want it to show something like 'keys=&theme=operateur' instead of 'keys=&theme=2'.

I tried configuring contextual filters, but nothing seems to work.